# socketexception connection failed (os error permission denied errno = 13)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

The Flutter Android application doesn't connect to the host server. This simple application takes the host server's IP address and port number. But it does not connect to the host. The code is like this:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Server Connection App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Server Connection'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _ipController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _portController = TextEditingController();
  String _response = '';

  void _connectToServer() async {
    String ipAddress = _ipController.text;
    int port = int.tryParse(_portController.text) ?? 0;

    try {
      final client = HttpClient();
      final request = await client.get(ipAddress, port, '/');
      final response = await request.close();
      final responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      setState(() {
        _response = responseBody;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      setState(() {
        _response = 'Error connecting to the server: $e';
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Enter IP Address:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _ipController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter IP Address',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Text(
              'Enter Port Number:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _portController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter Port Number',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _connectToServer,
              child: Text('Connect'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Text(
              'Response:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
            ),
            Text(
              _response,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error message is:
`socketexception connection failed (os error permission denied errno = 13)`

I tried modifying the AndroidManifest.xml file by adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

into it. But it still doesn't work.
Thank you in advance for your help. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also include the ip, host you tried to connect for more clarity

Comment: @YatinjSutariya Sure, ipAddress=192.168.4.1 and port=80.

Comment: Finally, I solved the problem. I have given internet permission in my app's ```android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml ```. However, I must define permissions in ```android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml```.